# No Hebrew in OS X Android emulation

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device, hebrew

I've created an Android 4.4.2 AVD running under OS X. I want to set its language to Hebrew. When I select Languages from the Android settings, I get a whole list of languages, including two Arabic variants, but no Hebrew.

I tried creating an Android 5.0.1 AVD, and there, too, there's no Hebrew. Applications can display Hebrew characters, but I want the AVD to support Hebrew because I need to test Hebrew input, as well.

UPDATE:
This question is OS X specific. On Windows all my Android AVDs have Hebrew as an optional language.

Comment: Have you heard about a website called Google? Try it! For example with "android emulator hebrew".

Comment: 20.3K rep and still does not understand how SO works...

Comment: I just fired up Genymotion and Hebrew is supported.

Comment: Yeah, I can Google. The links are all old and refer to Windows. I have Hebrew in my Windows Android Emulator, the problem is on OS X.

Comment: @Emmanueland @RenniePet this is a legitimate question. I don't really understand what you are ranting about. there is not a single clear answer when googling `android emulator hebrew`

Answer (score 0):

you can choose the language of the device in settings, you can choose the needed physical input you need :)

Good Luck!